# Why do historically locked posts not show up/down vote buttons, but collaborative effort locks do?

Tags: support, locked-posts, historical-lock

I've come across two different questions, one having a historical lock and one having a collaborative effort lock. I wasn't able to vote on either of them, but the historically locked post did not even show the up/down vote buttons, but the collaborative effort locked post did:
[image]
[image]

Why do they show up on the collaborative effort posts if you can't vote on it anyway?

Comment: I was under the impression that wiki-locks didnt disable voting...

Comment: @TinyGiant I thought so too, but apparently not. Try voting on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17271319/how-do-i-install-pip-on-macos-or-os-x) for example; it doesn't work.

Comment: Voting on the _answers_ there works, just not on the question.

Comment: Cross-site duplicate: [Inconsistency of UI between locked and historically locked](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/309572/inconsistency-of-ui-between-locked-and-historically-locked)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

A historical lock freezes the question *and all of its answers* in time, usually permanently. A historical lock essentially says "this page is archived and read-only" (note my use of the word "page").

A collaborative effort lock locks the question from edits, votes, and answers, because Stack Overflow doesn't have a dedicated "question with single wiki answer" format and instead misappropriates regular post locks to restrict adding new answers. Regular locks are designed to be

- temporary by default, permanent or indefinite in unusual circumstances (e.g. if a post sees continuous spam or vandalism for many months or years with no signs of it stopping)
- on a per-post basis, for any of a number of moderation reasons such as vandalism, off-topic comments, or some other dispute

and keeping the vote buttons visible is meant to illustrate the temporary and relatively "minor" (for lack of a better word) nature of these locks.

I do believe there should be a dedicated post type for these kinds of questions since locking a question the way it's currently done prevents edits or votes, to much detriment of the question itself.

Comment: A "merged" post is never a _temporary_ lock, yet it shows the voting arrows.

Comment: @Cœur: Again, the lock on merged posts is more like regular locks than historical locks. It's more of a functional thing. It's not there to indicate that merged posts are "archived". I knew someone was going to pick on the use of "temporary" and it is absolutely not the best choice of word to use but it's really difficult for me to explain these nuances.

Comment: Why do collaborative effort locks lock votes?

Comment: @Donald Duck: As I said, they're implemented using the same regular lock mechanism as all other lock options, to the detriment of the question. I can't comment on the design decision, mostly because there's no way to rationalize disabling voting as appropriate for collaborative effort questions.